# Como hacer esto con ORM Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm

En mi base de datos cuento con las siguientes tablas:

Documento (idDoc, titulo, tipo)

Proyecto (idProyecto,nombre)

DocumentoProyecto (idDP,fk_Documento,fk_Proyecto)

Necesito a saber como hacer esto con el ORM de Laravel
en una sola consulta.

1.- Filtrar aquellos documentos cuyo tipo sea 2 (int)

2.- De los documentos resultantes,se deben comparar aquellos que tengan el proyecto "Amigos".

3.- La consulta me debe arrojar unicamente los documentos que tengan el proyecto "Amigos" y el tipo 2.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que toda tu consulta se podría resumir en algo como esto, suponiendo que los campos y las relaciones estén de la siguiente forma:

```
class Proyecto {

  public function documentos()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(App\Documento, 'documento_proyecto')
  }

}


Proyecto::whereHas('documentos', function ($query) {
     $query->where('tipo', 2);
})->where('nombre', 'Amigos')->get();
```

Comment: el segundo where debería ir por dentro de la propia función anónima que declaraste no? y solo el get como método externo

Comment: según lo que entendí esta buscando el nombre del proyecto

Comment: @Ccin está bien hecha la consulta, acabo de revisar los campos y había entendido de manera inversa las tablas. Esta solución es la correcta.